# Problems while using 'quickly create' on ubuntu.

Tags: quickly

I'm watching the "creating your first Ubuntu application". I typed into the terminal 
quickly create ubuntu application my browser, and I got this.

```
leife@tinetine:~$ quickly create ubuntu application mybrowser
ERROR: No template specified for command create.
Usage: quickly create <template> <project-name>
Candidate templates are: ubuntu-application, ubuntu-cli, ubuntu-flash-game.
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to write the command like

```
quickly create ubuntu-application mybrowser
```

you are missing the `-` between Ubuntu-application template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type `quickly create ubuntu-application`, as the answer told you (you missed the `-`)